# Maven copy resources executed twice once for profile once default

Tags: maven, maven-profiles, maven-resources-plugin

I have a maven project where I have defined a `profile` based build including a custom `maven-resource-plugin` configuration.

```
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>docker</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>resources</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>log4j2*.xml</exclude>
                                            <exclude>docker/*</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

Now when I am executing for example `mvn compile -P docker` I can see that the resource plugin is executed twice.

> INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:copy-resources (resources) @ mma-access-management-auth-server ---
>
> [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
>
> [INFO] Copying 2 resources
>
> [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ mma-access-management-auth-server ---
>
> [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
>
> [INFO] Copying 5 resources

Is this right? Do I really have to exclude all resources for the default build to avoid that they are copied again through the default-resources?

Comment: it sort of is. plugins can run several times in the life-cycle and even in the same phase. The hint would be the execution id you give: <id>resources</id> - if you want to replace the default you need to use the same execution id - if you want to place the configuration inside an execution block. If there are different ones the plugin runs per configured execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not bind the plugin to the generate-resources phase again.
You can change the configuration of the default execution when you use the configuration tag only.

```
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>docker</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>log4j2*.xml</exclude>
                                    <exclude>docker/*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

Comment: When I don't bind it to a phase/goal the plugin gets not executed?

Comment: Yes, when you don't bind it in the profile, the plugin is executed only once with the configuration specified in your profile.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have overlooked to put the configuration outside the executions section.